# Pronunciation of おう: long sound (chouonpu) or two separate vowels

Tags: pronunciation

**Google Translate**'s pronunciation for the word 思う sounds like /omou/ with two separate vowels sounds /o/ and /u/ at the end:

https://translate.google.com/?sl=ja&tl=en&text=%E6%80%9D%E3%81%86&op=translate

However, I learnt that for the *もう*, we should pronounce this part with a single /o/ with a longer length, like /o:/, so it should be /omo:/ instead of /omou/.

Is Google Translate's pronunciation incorrect in this case or am I wrong?